# Program counting minutes from start to stop. and generates txt report.

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file based application that installs a number of things on the machine . I would like in this context is a program that I eg can run via batch file example : "start count time " and stop count time , where it generates a message to the user or genereates a txt file with date,and spent time. It must also continue after restart but need not counting time in the restart process.

Comment: `time /t >> MyLogFile.txt`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not need a separate program for this.

It is quite possible for me to use clock from the computers.

```
Example
Batch start:
Get windows time / date , save to time.txt
Batch end :
Get windows time / date , save to time.txt
Simply calculate hour from start to end
```